# Jar file giving exception

Tags: jar, jvm, java, executable-jar

i have created jar file that run successfully on cmd like this:

> start javaw -Xmx1024m -jar JavaEdit.jar

My application is running by double click but when i perform a button click it gives  exception which is not happening when i am running it via CMD.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Editor.compileIt(Editor.java:2407)
    at Editor.CompileBtnActionPerformed(Editor.java:1412)
    at Editor.access$300(Editor.java:113)
    at Editor$7.actionPerformed(Editor.java:580)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why it happen, please help... Thanks

at line No 2407 in source code:

```
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(c,
            Locale.ENGLISH,
            null);
```

Comment: This looks more like a uninitialized variable in the user code. What is on line `Editor.java:2407`?

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` at line 2407 of the `Editor` class.

Comment: You have a `NullPointerException` as others have said. I believe this might have to do with the working directory. Are you doing any IO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible place for a `NullPointerException` is this line:

```
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(c,
```

where the `compiler` is `null`. You should add `println(System.getPropert("java.home"))` statement to see which JRE/JDK is running the application.

My guess is that your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to JDK and is in the `PATH`, but Windows is using JRE, as per ".jar" file association.

**UPDATE:**
You can run it with a `runapp.bat` file like this one:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\javaw.exe -Xmx1024m -jar JavaEdit.jar
```

The BAT file must be **in the same folder** as your JAR file.

**UPDATE2:**
Make sure you have defined the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. You check with this command:

```
c:\> echo %JAVA_HOME%
```

It should print out the location of your JDK - `C:\Program Files(x86)...`.

Comment: Yah, it is running form:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre

so, what should i do ?

Comment: You are probably using Windows 7 so to change JAR file association you go to Control Panel > search "file assoc" > click the "Change the file type ..." > locate ".jar" > Change program... > Browse ... > and  find your `${JDK}/bin/javaw.exe`.

Comment: can i do it by batch file ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `call %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe -jar ....`.

Comment: But if you want to hide the Command Prompt window you can use http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ to create an EXE for your application.

Comment: _i still having same problem ?_
when i run batch command call %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe -jar it give:
**The system cannot find the path specified.**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28200/discussion-between-akhilesh-dhar-dubey-and-cebence)

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting a null `JavaCompiler` (or an NPE getting it), then I'm guessing you run your application with a JRE and not a JDK.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html)

> Returns: the compiler provided with this platform or null if no compiler is provided

Comment: But i have seen 'JavaCompiler.class' file is presented in 'jre/bin/rt.jar'. Then Why it is happening ?

Comment: The class may be present, but the JRE does not come with a compiler, so the `ToolProvider` will return `null`